# How to stop network profile from coming back after deletion in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I am trying to change the password for a wifi network connection on Windows 7. But the old password keeps coming back. So I'd like to simply delete the old connection ("my-network") and just create a new one.

Here's what I tried:

1. Control Panel > Network and Sharing Center > Manage Wireless Networks > Click the network, then click Delete.

   Reboot the computer, and "my-network" is back in the control panel.
2. Open `regedit` search for "my-network" in all keys, values and data, and delete all keys that contain the value.

   Reboot the computer, and "my-network" is back in the control panel.
3. Open `cmd` as Administrator, then `netsh wlan delete profile name=my-network` as per this answer: [How can I clear out all old Wi-fi settings on Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/7197/how-can-i-clear-out-all-old-wi-fi-settings-on-windows-7)

   Reboot the computer, and the network is back when I type `netsh wlan show profiles`

How can I remove this network (profile?) for good?

Comment: Is your computer a member of a Windows domain?

Comment: @Steven No, it looks like it's in a workgroup. How does that affect the network config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After deleting a wifi network connection on Windows, it should never come again after reboot.

Your network connection seems not being stored by Windows, but by a 3rd party wifi managers which stores all profiles you have connected to in the past and reconfigures Windows when you restart your computer.

For instance, Intel® PROSet/Wireless Software acts like that but it can be the cause of any other software. Lots of new computers come with such utility pre-installed. It might also be installed when you update your drivers.

So, you should uninstall such a tool and then, delete again your network profile.

Comment: ok, this is tricky. I'm not the main admin on this computer and can only access it about 3 weeks per year (it's my father-in-law's), so I don't feel good experimenting with uninstalling/reinstalling software on it that the main admins may need. However, I'm pretty sure this is the answer, since there is a 3rd party wifi manager running on it. So I'll probably accept this as the answer, unless a final check turns out otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

There is a missing step in what you did.

You have done :

> Control Panel > Network and Sharing Center > Manage Wireless Networks > Click the network, then click Delete.

You should follow by going back to
*Network and Sharing Center > Change adapter settings*, right-click
*Wireless Network Connection* and then click *Connect/Disconnect*.

Click the Refresh button to update the view of the available wireless networks.
You may connect to it again if you wish by using the new password.

If the old password returns again, then it is reinstated by some
installed manager, as described by @Trevor65.